# Magento 2 putting background images in body

Tags: html, css, content-management-system, magento2

I want to put a background image in my magento 2 but i can't because i think its not possible to put a body tag in their editor!

I want to put a background picture in the black box

[image]

I tried to put a body tag but i't wont work

[image]

```
<style xml="space"><!--
    .p1 {
        color :red;
    }
    body {
        background-color= firebrick;
    }
--></style>

<body class="body">
    <p class="p1">Hello</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need to add **background-color** property it must looks like that :

```
background-color: #333;
```

instead of  =   it must be  :